# How do I set the default namespaces in MapHttpRoute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

With the standard MapRoute method a can pass a string collection representing the namespaces in which to search for my controller. This seems to have disappeared from MapHttpRoute. How does one define the default namespaces using the new API routing?

Comment: While you can't define a default namespace out of the box, I followed this tutorial to allow namespaces to be included in the url paths: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx

Comment: Link in the comment above has gone stale, it looks like it now lives here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/

Answer (score 17):

We had this problem with the Umbraco core so we created our own IHttpControllerSelector, the source code can be found here:

https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Selectors/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

You can also install nuget package [`WebAPIContrib`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebAPIContrib/) which contains `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector`.

To register this you can do this on app startup:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),
    new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

The implementation is pretty straight forward and only deals with routes that have the "Namespaces" datatoken set which you have to manually set since the MapHttpRoute doesn't support this. Example:

```
var r = routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
r.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] {"Foo"};
```

The implementation also only caches controllers found with duplicate names since the underlying default implementation removes duplicates from it's cache.

Comment: This works really well, thanks! 
You may have to initialise `r.DataTokens` to a new `RouteValueDictionary` to avoid a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @mac10688 I am getting the same error r.DataTokens is read-only. How did you fix this?

Comment: @123456789 I was trying to mix mvc controllers with web api. After this block, I decided it wasn't worth it. I didn't fix it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the WebApiContrib project has added this functionality there: http://bit.ly/1M298i7 so you can probably just use that lib to get it all working now.

Comment: Ah, just realized why people were getting the error that DataTokens is readonly: It's because there are two types of 'routes': System.Web.Routing.Route which they are not read-only and then System.Web.Http.Routing.Route which they are read-only. The way that I've always had this working is based on an extension method on the normal route table, for example RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute will map a webapi route but return a System.Web.Http.Routing.Route, not sure how that works internally but it works.

Comment: If any part of your application depends on [ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx) then this implementation will break it. ApiExplorer cannot chew the duplicate controller names. For example [swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), .net implementation of [swagger](http://swagger.io/) does break, since it's using the api explorer. Beware.

Comment: link is dead (404). https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7.1.5/src/Umbraco.Web/WebApi/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

Comment: here you go: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Web/WebApi/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

Comment: The Controller selector is good, but is **case sensitive**.
If you want case insensitive calls to your api, you need to edit line 89 to:
`result.TryAdd(string.Format("{0}-{1}", controllerTypeGroup.Key.ToLower(), controllerType.Namespace),`

and line 59 to:
`if (_duplicateControllerTypes.Value.TryGetValue(string.Format("{0}-{1}", controllerNameAsString.ToLower(), ns), out descriptor))`

Answer (score 13):

That feature does not exist currently.

Comment: @marcind does this exist in the RTM version of MVC4?

Comment: Any workaround for this besides renaming my controllers with conflicting names?  I'm trying to inherit controllers from an existing web api project, but not change the urls that my clients' request.

Comment: @marcind: As I saw, this feature still doesn't exist in the current MVC/Web API 5 beta. Any plans to support it in MVC/Web API 5?

Answer (score 2):

Although the feature does not exist at this moment, you *can* however do this by implementing your own IHttpControllerSelector.

This blog article digs a bit into the details: [ASP.NET Web API: Using Namespaces to Version Web APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set default namespaces with Web API, it will search for controllers in all namespaces in the referenced assemblies (public types with name ending by 'Controller' which implement IHttpController).

Comment: "You don't need to set default namespaces with Web API" - not always true. There are scenarios when you do, which is why the op asked.

Answer (score -3):

Before the MapHttpRoute Factory call add

```
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Namespace.Full.Controllers");
```

Comment: We are talking about MapHttpRoute